# Exporting data from Lotus Approach. Why are some field names italicized?

Tags: database, data-transfer, lotus-approach

I'm trying to export data from a legacy Lotus Approach program. For each table in the drop down list it shows the fields available for export. The weird thing is that the last 39 fields for every table are the same and the names are italicized.

I've been going through the exported data, and some of the those fields are identical between tables, while others have slight differences.

I'm trying to wrap my head around what's going on here so any help is appreciated. The version of Approach that I am using is 9.7.

Thanks!

[image: Lotus Approach Export Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

The fields in italics are not "real" fields in the database. They are calculated fields created from two or more of the actual fields.  They are, in effect, variables that are populated when the application opens.  For example, combining First_Name and Last_Name that ARE real fields, can be placed in the calculated field *Full_Name* (by the program).